# Nuget does not respect package reference config?

Tags: nuget, cefsharp, csproj, nuget-package-restore

I have a project that needs to target multiple versions of CefSharp (it's an addin to a parent that uses CefSharp and dictates the versions).  I have the following in my .csproj file using package references to the NuGet packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x64" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug 2020' Or '$(Configuration)' == '2020'">
  <Version>3.3325.1758</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Common" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug 2020' Or '$(Configuration)' == '2020'">
  <Version>65.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug 2020' Or '$(Configuration)' == '2020'">
  <Version>65.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x64" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug 2020' And '$(Configuration)' != '2020'">
  <Version>3.2987.1601</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Common" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug 2020' And '$(Configuration)' != '2020'">
  <Version>57.0.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug 2020' And '$(Configuration)' != '2020'">
  <Version>57.0.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

When I build this in the 'Debug 2017' configuration it SHOULD give me version 57.0.0 but what I get is 65.0.1 all around.  If I remove the references to 65 altogether but do nothing to the conditions or build config, so now it looks like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x64" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug 2020' And '$(Configuration)' != '2020'">
  <Version>3.2987.1601</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Common" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug 2020' And '$(Configuration)' != '2020'">
  <Version>57.0.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug 2020' And '$(Configuration)' != '2020'">
  <Version>57.0.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

I get version 57.  That's great, but for the 2020 builds I need it to reference 65.0.1...  Why isn't it respecting the conditions??

Logically, based on the second test the v57 conditions have to be evaluating to true because it builds and outputs when the v65 references are not there.  That would lead me to believe that the top ones are evaluating to true as well and 'winning' giving me v65.  However, the condition statements are logical opposites and mutually exclusive are they not?  That would mean they CAN'T both be true...  What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Ran another test with only the v65 references in there (with conditions still) and I do get v65 dlls in the output...  How could those evaluate to true with the configuration named 'Debug 2017'?

Answer (score 2):

Ok after some additional research I figured it out thanks to [this link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5895).  Apparently package references don't support conditioning on configuring, only on target framework (ugh).  Per the workaround for the article you can use a Choose/When to do this.  Here is what I ended up with that seems to be working:

```
 <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug 2020' Or '$(Configuration)' == '2020'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x64">
          <Version>3.3325.1758</Version>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Common">
          <Version>65.0.1</Version>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf">
          <Version>65.0.1</Version>
        </PackageReference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug 2020' And '$(Configuration)' != '2020'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x64">
          <Version>3.2987.1601</Version>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Common">
          <Version>57.0.0</Version>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf">
          <Version>57.0.0</Version>
        </PackageReference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

**Edit**

I was still having a little trouble with the 'Otherwise' block so I switched it to two 'When' blocks with opposite conditions.  Doesn't look quite as clean but seems to work better...